# Are there Indicators of Attack or Indicators of Compromise (IoA, IoC) or suspicious events specific to stalkerware?

Tags: spyware, indicator-of-compromise

By stalkerware I mean the type of spyware that is typically marketed as a tool to catch a cheating spouse (or similar).

I am asking because the motive for this type of attack is somewhat different from other attacks. If the goal of an attacker using stalkerware is to catch me cheating, but I never cheat, then in theory they may just snoop to their heart's content - indefinitely.

Short of specifically screening for this type of malware using antivirus, are there any common Indicators of Attack or Indicators of Compromise specific to stalkerware that would possibly give the victim a clue that they were being tracked?

Is there a way for a victim to learn they are being stalked without tipping off the stalker?

Comment: Your definition of IoC is not correct or accurate and your examples are in error. Those are not IoCs. So, it will be difficult to use your framing to answer the question. Especially when you want to exclude the *actual* IoC; the binary itself. What you appear to be asking is: "how can I tell if someone wants to know I'm cheating?" But I'm really not sure what you want to know or what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you @schroeder, I edited the question to be clearer. The question is basically "how can I tell if someone is stalking me?" - which I want to point out is a different question from "how can I tell if someone wants to know I am cheating?" A person wanting to know if I am cheating has a choice in whether or not to engage in stalking behaviors in an effort to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @schroeder mentioned in the comments, your definition of an IoC is a little off. I won't go into great detail but I'll prefix this answer with a brief definition just so we're on the same page.

An IoC is an evidentiary article that (unsurprisingly) indicates compromise. An IoC is *not* the same as a suspicious event. A suspicious event might be that an email you hadn't read was marked as read when you went to your inbox. This itself does not *indicate* a compromise, because there are other possible explanations - you could've misclicked, forgotten you'd read it, or accidentally selected it in a "mark selected as read" operation. If you then looked at the login history for your account and found one from a device or location you didn't recognise, *that* is an indicator of compromise.

When we're talking about IoCs in the context of malware, it often refers to metadata that can be used as part of automated threat detection (e.g. AV, EDR, HIDS, NIDS), e.g. in a rule-based format like YARA.

Some examples of these types of IoCs used to detect specific malware families are:

- Cryptographic hashes of files
- Fuzzy / contextual hashes of files (e.g. PE section hashes, ssdeep)
- Strings or other byte sequences present in the files
- Names of executables
- Locations in which malicious executables will run from
- Details of stolen code-signing certificates used to sign malware (e.g. cert hash)
- Names and other properties of services that malware will register
- Names and other properties of drivers that the malware will install
- Names of system objects (e.g. events, mutexes, shared memory sections, etc.) that malware will create
- Names of registry keys that the malware will read, write, modify, or create
- Audit logs that may be generated by the OS or SIEM (e.g. Sysmon) during the malware's operation
- DNS names that the malware will try to resolve
- IP addresses that the malware will try to contact
- Patterns that command and control (C2) network traffic will match
- Configuration changes made to the system (e.g. adding firewall rules, disabling AV)
- Behavioural heuristics that are unique to the target (e.g. pattern of API calls, memory allocations in other processes, unusual modification of its own runtime environment, etc.)

To answer your question about whether there are IoCs specific to stalkerware as a class of malware, we should start with two more fundamental questions. First: what *is* stalkerware, in a concrete sense? Second: what specific measurable properties does stalkerware have that might point towards IoCs that are specific to it as a class of malware?

Stalkerware is any software or hardware that a stalker might use to gain information about the activities of a victim. This also includes "spouseware", although I consider that term to be both inaccurate and morally offensive, since it implies that a spouse or family member is doing something other than stalking when they use it, and that it is somehow more righteous or justifiable because of their relationship with the victim. While the common expectation of stalkerware is that it is something used by an ex-boyfriend or an obsessive weirdo, the majority of users are domestic abusers, people who would rather violate their partner's privacy than communicate with them, and controlling parents who have no respect for their child's privacy.

From a technical perspective, stalkerware can be anything from a remote monitoring app to a GPS tracker. Stalkerware applications designed for desktop operating systems may offer capabilities such as keylogging, web history logging, chat logging for common chat apps (e.g. WhatsApp, Telegram), dumping saved passwords, screenshotting / remote viewing, geolocation, access to the microphone and webcam, and many more invasive things. It could be implemented as a desktop application. It could be implemented as a service that runs as SYSTEM or root. It could be implemented as a kernel-mode driver.

The mechanisms by which these capabilities can be implemented are fairly open-ended, and the interfaces (e.g. APIs) offered by the operating system to interact with the components and resources needed to implement these capabilities are also used by legitimate non-malicious software. For example, stalkerware on Windows might take screenshots through the GDI APIs (`GetWindowDC` and `BitBlt`), or Direct3D (capturing the screen surface), or DXGI (desktop duplication with `IDXGIOutputDuplication`), or WindowsGraphicsCapture, or by simulating a `VK_SNAPSHOT` key event and extracting the image from the clipboard buffer. Each of these may also be used by normal non-malicious applications, e.g. Zoom/Skype/WebEx for screen-sharing, OBS, games, Windows Game Bar, FPS overlay tools, image editors, and many more.

This means that there's no *broad, measurable* IoC for software that includes these capabilities, and thus no broad IoCs unique to stalkerware. It is possible for an anti-malware product to heuristically detect that a program *might* be malicious based on it accessing a wide range of resources that are known to be associated with remote access trojans (RATs) and stalkerware, but this is not a direct indicator of compromise - it's a detection of suspicious behaviour.

It is my opinion that focusing on the technical aspects of stalkerware is the wrong way to approach the problem. As noted above, stalkerware is just malware used with a specific intent. At the implementation level it's a malicious program like any other. What makes stalkerware different from most malware is the malicious actor's relationship to the victim, their capabilities *outside* the technical domain, and how that restricts the victim's options when responding to uncovering stalkerware. It's a human problem, not a technical one. You can remove a banking trojan or cryptominer without fear that the person who installed it will assault or punish you, but that is rarely the case for victims of stalkerware. While it is important that technical advice for victims is accurate, advice on combatting stalkerware (both personally and at a societal level) should come from people who are well-qualified and well-informed on matters of abusive relationships and domestic violence. I am certainly not qualified to do that, and I will defer to victim advocacy groups such as [Coalition Against Stalkerware](https://stopstalkerware.org/).

Comment: "You can remove a banking trojan or cryptominer without fear that the person who installed it will assault or punish you, but that is rarely the case for victims of stalkerware."

Thank you. This sentence gets at the meat of my question. Since it can often be dangerous to remove this software based on the victim's situation, I was wondering if there was a way that someone might realize that they are a victim without drawing attention to their knowledge of it. I also appreciate the correction on my definition of IoC. That was helpful, as is the link to Coalition Against Stalkerware.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are IOCs to detect Spyware/Stalkerware, but i think many of they are quite out of reach for the average user, unless they worked at a company with the capabilities of detection such traffic on their public corporate WiFi.

Regardless, here is one example with various types of indicators:
https://github.com/Te-k/stalkerware-indicators

The idea behind such detection is to detect IF you are being spied upon or stalked so you can control what the intercepting party see. There is no way to salvage it using technical measures, except for getting a new phone and a new cloud account, as the attacker would probably have access to that too.

My sister were (or rather still is) stalked and has received death threats and also were on the edge of comitting suicide, and we did a complete replacement of everything: phones, email and social media as we also emergency evacuated her to a new town. I *honestly* don't know if they had anything installed on her phone, but being the security savvy guy in the family, i made the decision that we couldn't risk it.

There is no need for IOCs if you have clear indications that some psychopath is spying on you, only quick actions are of value.